# Are phrases 'in another word' and 'not another word' correct?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I have two questions here:

1. Can 'in another word' mean 'in other words'? I see the example in the dictionary on my cellphone:

> In another word, Jesus got the abandon that we deserved.

2. Is 'not another word' a phrase? I guess it means 'not saying another word' or 'don't say this any more'. Have I got it right?

Here is another example:
[image]

Comment: What dictionary is that?

Comment: It's an app installed on my phone. It might not be a good one. I also updated with another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope `In another word` is a wrong phrase for such case. Common and correct is `in other words`.

As for `not another word` - I think it's correct and could mean `say no more` or have literal meaning based on context e.g. `zebra is not another word for horse`